# I just accidentally uninstalled a lot of programs, is there way to get all of them back at once?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

Okay, so, this question may have been asked before, but I really need help.

I ran `sudo aptitude`to find a specific package that I wanted to delete. I pressed "Install/Remove Pkgs" and there was a section of packages that were to be removed because they were "no longer used". So, I did a noobish move and pressed "g" to remove these seemingly unused packages.

The menu closed and the terminal processes began, I watched. I started seeing programs that were **obviously** being used by me. So, I hurried up and exited terminal to stop the process.

A few moments later, two programs "Puddle tag" and the Software Center on my dock became grayed (they were open at the time) and disappeared. A **handful** of used/needed programs seemed to be uninstalled. And I am now at a lost of what to do. But I have a little hope.

I went to the history log and it has everything that was uninstalled [which was a crap load of things] thankfully. Is there a way to batch download/install all of these back onto my computer with this information? I'm assuming it's impossible, but is it possible? There is no way I can see myself doing all of this one at a time, it's way too much. Oh, and at the end of the log, there was an error

`Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Original Poster states in comments on answers that they are using Elementary OS, which is offtopic here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```

Comment: I think I asked this in the wrong place and screwed myself more. What you said did work in terms of getting the software center back and and native applications, etc., the other 100's of packages/programs weren't recovered unfortunately. But what also happened was the desktop environment changed (I'm running elementary OS freya) and it's all jacked. I thought that since elementary was based on ubuntu, it was virtually the same thing, apparently not. This is usually where I get all my answers from. How stupid of me, thank you for the help, though.